# Change the size of the traffic light

Tags: javascript, css

I have this code, but the traffic light is too big and the buttons are separated far apart. I tried changing the PX but it made the traffic light squares instead of circles and smooth rectangle for the shape of the traffic light.
Any help?
Thanks!
This is what happens to me. [image]

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  height: 550px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've changed your code to be contained inside a snippet. Although I did notice in your original code you hade a `<html>` element inside the `<body>` element, you should remove this as it's not valid HTML. P.S. Nice traffic light!

Comment: Hi, 
I have removed the <html> and it made all my shapes into squares and rectangle. 
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Internet and Chrome

Comment: ..or you could simply reduce those huge margins between buttons to match the traffic lights, like .button { margin: 35px 40px; }

Comment: That worked for but the shapes have changed again.

Comment: Its just funny, because if I try out your example, edit the properties I described its working without any issues.

Comment: I have added a picture to the question.

Comment: Is this bugging out in both Chrome and IE(11?)

Comment: Yes, 
maybe it's this computer, I will try a different computer when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply change the height and width of `.bulb`and `#traffic-light` classes.

Like so

```css
#traffic-light {
   height: 400px;
   width: 150px;
   ...
}

.bulb {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   ....
}
```

To edit the space between the bulbs, simply play around with the `margin` property of the `.bulb` until it suits your liking.

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  height: 400px;
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it changes the shapes of the circles and the smooth rectangle to right angle squares and rectangle.
Thanks anyway

Comment: They mean edit the existing values of the `height` and `width`, don't remove the other CSS rules

Comment: Yes indeed George, he needs to edit the existing properties, not remove them.

Answer (score 0):

To change the distance between the buttons just reduce the margin-top and margin-bottom of those buttons (last CSS rule in my snippet):

To reduce the size of the traffic-light itself, erase the height (to make it dependent on its content), change its width and change the width and height of the bulbs.

I am not sure if this is what you want but it should lead you into the right direction.

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = stopRed;
document.getElementById('slowButton').onclick = slowYellow;
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = goGreen;
document.getElementById('Lights').onclick = Lights;
document.getElementById('autoLights').onclick = autoLights;

function stopRed() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}

function slowYellow() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "orange";
}

function goGreen() {
  Lights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "green";
}


function Lights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}


function lightOne(num) {
  Lights();
  switch (num) {
    case 1:
      stopRed();
      break;
    case 2:
      slowYellow();
      break;
    case 3:
      goGreen();
      break;
    default:
      alert("you made some error");
  }
}

counter = 0;
maxSec = 3;

function timer() {
  setTimeout(function() {

    counter++;
    lightOne(counter);
    if (counter == maxSec) {
      return;
    }
    timer();
  }, 2000);
}

function autoLights() {
  counter = 1;
  lightOne(counter);
  timer();
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#controlPanel {
  float: left;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.button {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 90px 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#traffic-light {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}

.bulb {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 25px auto;
  transition: background 500ms;
}

#controlPanel>h1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="controlPanel">
  <h1 id="stopButton" class="button">Stop</h1>
  <h1 id="slowButton" class="button">Slow</h1>
  <h1 id="goButton" class="button">Go</h1>
  <h1 id="Lights" class="button">Clear</h1>
  <h1 id="autoLights" class="button">Auto</h1>
</div>

<div id="traffic-light">
  <div id="stopLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="slowLight" class="bulb"></div>
  <div id="goLight" class="bulb"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a ratio of 2.75 for #traffic-light height to width .

Example:

```
#traffic-light {
  height: 275px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Reduce the margin between buttons to make the buttons closer.